# process.env.NODE_ENV is not getting set correctly in my Next.js app

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables

I am having trouble figuring out the problem with my app. I have an `.env.local` file and I set the `NODE_ENV` to `development`. But in my logs, I am getting a value of `production`. There's no other place in my app where the NODE_ENV can be seen.

I run my app using:
`next build && next start -p 3000`

I also tried running:
`NODE_ENV=development && next build && next start -p 3000`

Both didn't work.

Here's a screenshot of my problem.
[image]

Comment: The `next` command probably spawns a sub-shell so your non-exported environment variable doesn't carry through. Try `export NODE_ENV=development`

Comment: Values in `.env` files won't overwrite existing environment variables either

Comment: @Phil got this figured out right after I posted my question. You are right with the export NODE_ENV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Phil suggested in his comment, the NODE_ENV doesn't get carried through when nextjs starts. I needed to do an `export NODE_ENV=development` for it to work.